# Google Play Order Statuses - what is the difference between "Canceled" and "Payment declined"?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-developers-console, in-app-subscription

I have an app that offers inapp payments on Google Play.

Unfortunately, in the "Order management" page I see a lot of payments "Canceled" and it is unclear to me what that means. I have searched the web for an answer but couldn't find one :(

The issue is that the google doc about this is unclear (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2741495?hl=en#zippy=%2Cusing-the-play-console-website%2Cusing-the-play-console-app).

It says for "canceled" :

Canceled : Payment was canceled during processing by the user or due to a payment issue.

And for "declined" :

Payment declined : User's payment method was declined.

What is the difference between both ? If a "payment issue" is the reason for the order canceled, shouldn't that appear as "Payment declined" instead ?

About a quarter of the orders we received are shown as "Canceled", so this is concerning to me.

[Google Play Orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oG58M.png)

Thanks you very much for your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Canceled -> Payment was canceled during processing by the user or due to a
payment issue. It means that your payment method was added
successfully but there is a problem during your payment. e.g:
Insufficient balance in your account or payment rejected by bank
due to some reason
Payment declined -> User's payment method was declined. Your payment method is
declined like visa card or any other service you are using to add
payment.

For more information about payment statuses, you can visit this link
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2741495?hl=en